# Time and date from two different datetimes

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a datetime column in my table, and I want to update it so that it gets todays date but keeps the time part.

Examples:

```
2011-01-21 01:12...  -> 2013-04-23 01:12...
2012-04-20 19:22...  -> 2013-04-23 19:22...
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

regards Oskar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @date_old DATETIME
SELECT @date_old = '2011-01-21 01:12'

DECLARE @date_new DATETIME
SELECT @date_new = '2013-04-23 05:24'

SELECT CAST(CAST(@date_new AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(@date_old AS TIME)
```

Comment: This query returns 2013-04-23 01:12:00.000

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Here's a tested solution

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME2(7)
Declare @OldDate DateTime2(7)
SET @Today=GETDATE()

Select @OldDate = date From <SomeDatabase>

SELECT DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, @Today, @OldDate), @OldDate)
```

Here's with update:

```
Update <SomeDatabase>  Set date = DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, @Today, @OldDate), @OldDate) where date = @OldDate
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the table use `self join` and use the method  by @Devart to preserve the `time` but update the `date` value

```
Declare @Sample table ( myDate datetime )
Insert into @Sample
values
('2013-04-21 11:42:51.897'),('2013-04-22 13:42:51.897')
Select * from @Sample

Update t
set myDate =convert(datetime,convert(date,getdate())) + convert (time,s.mydate)
from @Sample t inner join @Sample s
on s.myDate=t.myDate
Select * from @Sample
```

Initial Result

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║         myDate          ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 2013-04-21 11:42:51.897 ║
║ 2013-04-22 13:42:51.897 ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

Final Result

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║         myDate          ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 2013-04-23 11:42:51.897 ║
║ 2013-04-23 13:42:51.897 ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```